# Move columns to another sheet based on the cell value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell, multiple-columns, move

I'm looking to move a column to another sheet based on the cell value in a given row. I was able to do this for rows but not columns.

```
function onEdit(event) {
// assumes source data in sheet named CURRENT
// target sheet of move to named COMPLETE
// test column with yes/no is col 1 or A
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "Goals 3-6 Months" && r.getColumn() == 4 && 
r.getValue() == "Done") {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Goals Done");
if(targetSheet.getLastRow() == targetSheet.getMaxRows()) {

targetSheet.insertRowsAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow(), 20); //inserts 20 
rows after last used row
}
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome. You've given only the briefest of explanations of your problem, but you haven't given a good explanation of what you are trying to do &/or why. You provided some code but we shouldn't have to read/review code to understand your question. In addition, the code is internally inconsistent. Would you please edit your question to provide more information. If your existing code works, then explain how it doesn't meet your needs, AND show what efforts you have made to develop your own new code. If the existing code doesn't work, please show the error message,

Comment: Regarding your code, it is internally inconsistent: 1) "source data in sheet named CURRENT" but `IF` comparison refers to `Goals 3-6 Months`; 2) "test column ... is col 1 or A" but `IF` comparison refers to Column 4; 3) "test column with yes/no" but `IF` comparison refers to "Done"; 4) "target sheet ... named COMPLETE" but `IF` refers to "Goals Done". 5) FWIW, `r.getValue()` is unnecessary since the onEdit trigger returns the [value](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) (such as `event.value`).